# Creating Graphics2D causes glfwPollEvents to freeze

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am creating my own game engine using lwjgl. (Java OpenGL)

My application runs fine when the following code is commented out:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
```

Otherwise, the application freezes when calling `glfwPollEvents()`.

I have tried calling `g2d.dispose()` but it made no difference.

I am using Graphics2D to create a font bitmap. Are there any alternatives? I don't know what is causing `glfwPollEvents()` to freeze and how Graphics2D would affect it. Any ideas?

Edit 1:

VisualVm shows 2 new threads running in the application
[image]

Both of which are "waiting" and run for 0ms. I couldn't find any other difference in preformance when running the program with the snippet above and without it.

Comment: You can use VisualVM tool (https://visualvm.github.io/) to connect to your app and view details about the currently running threads (called thread dump). It should give you a clearer view of the situation and you can add it to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LWJGL/GLFW application cannot exist alongside the AWT Toolkit and its Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT). You should only use AWT via headless mode. See https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/headless.html for this.

Basically, the first thing that happens when you touch an AWT/Swing class is that AWT starts its own Event Dispatcher Thread. That thread is responsible for querying the OS for window event messages to dispatch to its own event handling logic to react to window event messages like "window closed" or "user moved mouse over window". So, AWT basically does the same thing that GLFW does with its `glfwPollEvents()`.

But, since there is only *one* event message queue per process, both calls steal each other's information away and in your case AWT's EDT thread processes window event message for your GLFW window (which it discards). But, those window message events will then be gone (from the OS's point of view, because the process already polled them), making GLFW's `glfwPollEvents()` call and the underlying OS call not return and process any events.

To solve this problem and still be able to use *some* functionality from AWT/Swing, you can use the headless mode, which you can enable via the JVM system parameter `java.awt.headless` = `true`, such as via:

`java -Djava.awt.headless=true ...`

As an alternative for rendering a font bitmap, you can also use stb_truetype, which LWJGL 3 provides bindings for.